# New developer...my hello world app isn't working. What's wrong with my strings?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've added a button that I want to essentially toggle a label from "Hello World" to "Goodbye World", right now it just says "Goodbye World" and doesn't change....what am I doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSString *mystr = @"Hello World";

    if (strcmp(label.text, mystr) == 0) {
        label.text = @"Goodbye World";
    }
    else
    {
        label.text = @"Hello World";
    }
    //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", strcmp(label.text, @"Hello World")];
}
```

Comment: What do you initially pass in label.text??

Comment: "Go on...press me", but it is supposed to toggle.  It shouldn't matter what the label starts at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"Hello World"]) {
        label.text = @"Goodbye World";
} 
else
{
        label.text = @"Hello World";
}
```

Comment: This code worked!  What is the purpose of the brackets [] around the code in the if(...) block?  I'm more of a C/C++/C# programmer so this is sort of strange for me.

Comment: Brackets around statements is the syntax in Objective-C.. if you want to call a method on an object the syntax is: [myObject myMethod];

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you'd be safer using Cocoa's NSString methods for comparing strings.  Try "isEqualToString".

Comment: I found that, but I'm struggling a bit with the weird Xcode syntax.  I know that @'s are used for string literals, but why the brackets around the piece of code?  And why the colon after isEqualToString:, I'd expect ()'s.  Is there a good syntax resource to start with?

Comment: @'s are used to create static NSString instances, not just strings.  You can still define C strings without the @ symbol, but generally you're better off in Cocoa working with NSStrings.Time to break out some documentation on Objective-C and Cocoa!